# Download Only Newly Purchased Albums and Tracks from Google Music

Tags: google-play-music

Using Google Music, it is possible to:

- "Download my library" via Google Music Manager
- "Download free and purchased" via Google Music Manager
- Download specific albums via the Google Music web application

I want to keep a particular computer synchronized with my Google Music library, but I don't want to have to download each new album that I purchase. For one, this uses up one of my two downloads of that particular album; for another, it seems like the ability to synchronize only newly purchased albums and tracks should be included functionality.

**Is there a way to download only the albums and tracks purchased since the last local synchronization?**

Answer (score 2):

This procedure *works* (on Linux, at least), but is time-consuming and bandwidth heavy.

1. Purchase a few albums via Google Play
2. In Google Music Manager, select "Download Free and Purchased"
3. Wait for 1500 songs to download.
4. Run a script to delete duplicate files that are created by the previous steps.

**Script to clean the Music/ directory:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script searches for duplicate files in the Music subdirectory
# stores those files in 'duplicates'
# and then deletes those files

find Music -name *\(1\).mp3 > duplicates

while read line;
    do rm "$line" ;
done < duplicates
```